# Charities that accept bike donations

Tags: reference, charities

I have a few old-but-still-working bikes collecting dust. Instead of trashing them, I'd like to give them to a charity so they can have a new life. I figured we could make a list of charities who accept bike donations.

One per post, please specify location and website (if any).

Comment: Please make a wiki, seems like I can't figure out how.

Comment: done. Also, I edited your title to be easier to scan -- is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @neilfein: absolutely

Answer (score 9):

There is a Wiki with an [International List of Bike Collectives and Community Orgainizations](http://www.bikecollectives.org/wiki/index.php?title=Community_Bicycle_Organizations&Itemid=100015) at BikeCollectives.org.

There are many other organizations, like the Salvation Army in the US, that take almost any item and either operate second-hand stores or sell the items to other thrift shops.  I prefer to deal with organizations like the [Salt Lake City Bike Collective](http://www.slcbikecollective.org/) because I know the bike is going to checked well and repaired if needed before being returned to the community.

Answer (score 4):

In Boulder, Colorado, [Community Cycles](http://communitycycles.org/get-involved/donate.html) accepts donated bicycles and puts them to good use. Their website lists [other bike collectives](http://communitycycles.org/links/bike-collectives.html) across North America that may make a good starting point for finding a similar organization elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

In Madison, Wisconsin, [Red Bikes](http://redbikes.org/) will take old bikes. Budget Bicycle Center on Regent Street is the dropoff location.

Answer (score 3):

In Austin, Texas, [Yellow Bike Project](http://austinyellowbike.org/) (YBP) accepts bikes and parts.  The organization is an opened all-volunteered based community.  I have volunteered to fix up bikes before and met people who have gotten free bikes from YBP :).

Answer (score 2):

In Rochester, MN the [Kiwanis club](http://sites.google.com/site/kiwanisbicyclerochestermn/) collects and reconditions bikes.  Most go to Christmas Anonymous, and a few others go to various worthy causes.  (There's often a need for adult bikes for getting back and forth to work.)  When I was unemployed a couple of years back I worked with them reconditioning the bikes.  Some very grungy bikes are taken in and lovingly restored, and the really lost causes are recycled (after stipping off any usable parts).

Answer (score 2):

In Hebden Bridge, UK you can drop your parts/whole bikes off at [Cycle Recycle](http://www.cyclerecycle.org.uk/).  It's a part of the Alternative Technology centre on the canalside.

Answer (score 2):

Christchurch, New Zealand has two

- [Icecycles](https://www.cyclingchurch.org.nz/html/icecycles.html) aimed at getting Inner City East people on bikes, and helping out those in the health system.
  Update - now only deals with a very specific geographic zone.
- [RAD bikes](http://www.radbikes.co.nz/) aiming more at self-reliance, repair your own bike with guidance and assistance.
- CBC Christchurch Bicycle Cooperative, including [PUFU aka Popup Fixup](https://www.actionbicycleclub.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Bristol, United Kingdon has the [Bristol Bike Project](http://www.thebristolbikeproject.org/) which does repairs, fixups, and sales of used bikes.  They also have specific fixup nights for different groups.

Answer (score 2):

[Goodwill](http://www.goodwill.org) takes bicycles in the US. They're all around the country. Note that the Goodwill shops are independently operated, so the quality and amount of community impact can be different in various parts of the country.